# Start background WatchOS app automatically on startup of Apple Watch 4 after reboot

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to start my written background app on my Apple Watch 4 automatically after rebooting Apple Watch 4, so that it runs continuously in the background.

I tried to reboot the Watch, but my app does not start automatically. It runs in the background again only if I start the app manually.

How can I achieve it? Can you provide me some code examples?

Comment: Requests for tutorials are off-topic here. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question and add what you've tried as a [mcve]. Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide detail on what your watchOS app does in the backgrounded state. I've tried rebooting Apple Watch while it was running one of the limited background capabilities available to developers, a workout, and it continued running in the background upon rebooting the device since the system displayed the workout glyph at the top of the watch face.

Comment: I've used the location Manager to let the watch app running in background. But with the Location Manager, the app will not start automatically after reboot.

So is the auto-start feature only possible for the workout background-mode?